# solr - replication failure - expected behavior?

Tags: solr

My slave polls every ten minutes, but my master only indexes once a day.

Every time my slave polls but my master has not been updated, it's recorded as a replication failure in replication.properties.

Is this expected behavior?  It seems to me that this should not be considered a failure.

```
#Replication details
#Fri Mar 02 08:23:38 EST 2012 

replicationFailedAtList=1330692602649,1330692000359,1330691401390,1330690800157,1330690200096,1330689600014,1330689000012,1330688400011,1330687800013,1330687200013 
previousCycleTimeInSeconds=1418 timesFailed=1675 
indexReplicatedAtList=1330694618838,1330692602649,1330692000359,1330691401390,1330690800157,1330690200096,1330689600014,1330689000012,1330688400011,1330687800013 
indexReplicatedAt=1330694618838 replicationFailedAt=1330692602649 
lastCycleBytesDownloaded=14445955753 timesIndexReplicated=1699
```

EDIT:
Master is set to replicate on Optimize.

The failed replications list stops growing after the successful replication occurs.  I'm not sure when they start up again, but perhaps at some point after the master starts its update on the next day?

My understanding of replication is that the slave checks the index version and if they're different the slave pulls the new data.  Considering master is set to replicate on Optimize, shouldn't the index version only increment when optimization is complete?  Is there some other mechanism by which the two solr instances communicate?

EDIT: 
I don't have any errors in the log.  I do notice that while there are a lot of lines on startup like this:

```
INFO: Adding  component:org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent@41217e67
Mar 1, 2012 11:53:49 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler inform
INFO: Adding  debug component:org.apache.solr.handler.component.DebugComponent@7df1bd98
Mar 1, 2012 11:53:49 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler inform
INFO: Adding  component:org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent@259a8416
Mar 1, 2012 11:53:49 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler inform
INFO: Adding  component:org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent@4355d3a3
Mar 1, 2012 11:53:49 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler inform
```

There is nothing about the ReplicationHandler.  Still, it does successfully replicate when the master is updated.

Comment: Sounds strange, can you post the error you get?

Comment: There's no error; added replications.properties file

Comment: Ok, and do you have errors in your solr log file?

Comment: Hm, maybe I don't have an error log on?  I only have request logs.  Will look into this.

Comment: By default you have everything within the catalina.out (on tomcat).

Comment: I'm running via jetty; saving jetty console output to a file and don't see any errors there.

Comment: Ok, but...is the timesFailed number increasing time by time?